# boost asio sockets keeps popping under /proc/pid/fd

Tags: linux, sockets, boost-asio

I'm sure sockets get closed everywhere in my application and i keep getting this newly created fd/socket files under my /proc/pid/fd/ is this normal. I'm sure it is not.

**connection.cpp**

```
 connection::start() {
    socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
    boost::asio::socket_base::non_blocking_io command(true);
    socket_.io_control(command);

    read_header();

    longevity_timer_.start();

    // log_->debugStream() << "listening";
  }

void connection::stop() {
    cancel_timeout();

    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;

    // initiate graceful connection closure & stop all asynchronous ops
    try {
      socket_.cancel();
      socket_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec);
      if (ignored_ec)
      {
          log_->errorStream() << "shutdown: bad socket; couldn't close cleanly" << ignored_ec.message();    
      }
      socket_.close(ignored_ec);
      if (ignored_ec)
      {
          log_->errorStream() << "close: bad socket; couldn't close cleanly" << ignored_ec.message();    
      }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
      log_->errorStream() << "bad socket; couldn't close cleanly";
    }
}
```

**lsof -p pid**

```
dakwakd 20733 root   18u  IPv4 647843      0t0      TCP localhost:35654->localhost:amqp (ESTABLISHED)
dakwakd 20733 root   19u  IPv4 647969      0t0      TCP localhost:35695->localhost:amqp (ESTABLISHED)
dakwakd 20733 root   20u  IPv4 647599      0t0      TCP localhost:35543->localhost:amqp (ESTABLISHED)
dakwakd 20733 root   21u  IPv4 647634      0t0      TCP localhost:35567->localhost:amqp (ESTABLISHED)
```

Now each time I get a new connection i made sure to stop it when im done with it.
but fd/socket files still grow rapidly under /proc/pid/fd/

How can i just make sure im not doing anything wrong

Comment: Did you use `strace` ? Did you compile with `g++ -Wall -g`? Did you use the `gdb` debugger?

Comment: yeah i use strace https://gist.github.com/waheedi/95fc30b5287098bde677

Comment: https://gist.github.com/waheedi/b39d0248338bc1e99d45 strace full log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a breakpoint at the top of connection::start.  Then when it gets hit, go through the call stack in the debugger to see where and how the method gets called to determine if it is as expected.

In the stop method, try moving cancel_timeout() inside the try/catch block since the code won't catch or log an error if it throws right now.

Try adding a debug call to log_->errorStream() at the top of both start and stop.  Print out the address of the _socket object - which I'm assuming is unique and created elsewhere for each new connection.  Make sure that for each debug print statement in the start method, a corresponding debug print statement is seen in the stop method with the correct address of the _socket object.  I suspect that they will not match and that your stop method is not getting called properly for some reason.  If this is true, then you will then need to investigate and debug why your stop method is not getting called to close the connection.

Comment: Thank you Bob. actually it seems the fd where generated from another lua application embedded inside this app. 
Thank you for your help again Bob.